# Radio button in .net mvc 5 implmented in html table with for loop

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

For asp.net mvc 5 , I need to display course and GradeA (radio button) , trying to implement rado button in loop but value of GradeA is null instead of true or false

Data is as follows :
Course  GradeA
Math    TRUE
Science FALSE
French  TRUE

Model is as follows:

```
public class selectStudentScore
  {
      public selectStudentScore()
      {
          StudentCourses = new List<CourseList>();
       }        

      public List<CourseList> StudentCourses{ get; set; }  

      public class CourseList
      {
          public Guid CourseId { get; set; }

          public string CourseName { get; set; }

          public bool? GradeA { get; set; }           
      }
  }
```

radio button in mvc 5 razor view as follows:

```
 <table class="spacer20">                      
    <tbody>
          @for (var i = 0; i < Model.StudentCourses.Count; i++)
          {
              <tr>
                  <td>                      
                      @Model.StudentCourses[i].CourseName                      
                  </td>

                  <td class="center">

<div class="field inline">                               
 @Html.RadioButton(string.Format("StudentCourses[{0}].GradeATrue", i), true, 
  Model.StudentCourses[i].GradeA.Value, 
  new { @id = string.Format("StudentCourses[{0}].GradeATrue", i) })
<label for="@string.Format("StudentCourses[{0}].GradeATrue", i)">&nbsp;</label>
                      </div>
   </td>
            <td class="center">
             <div class="field inline">       
 @Html.RadioButton(string.Format("StudentCourses[{0}].GradeAFalse", i), 
false, Model.StudentCourses[i].GradeA.Value, new 
{ @id = string.Format("StudentCourses[{0}].GradeAFalse", i) }) 
 <label for = "@string.Format("StudentCourses[{0}].GradeAFalse", i)" > 
&nbsp; </label>
                          </div>
              </td>                    
          </tr>   }
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Your `RadioButton()` makes no sense and its not clear what you trying to achieve with this. If you are wanting to bind to your `GradeA` property, then its `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.StudentCourses[i].GradeA, true) @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.StudentCourses[i].GradeA, false)` (but if your property is nullable, then you should either make it `[Required]` or have a 3rd radio button for a `null` value)

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I am trying to bind GradeA property to the radio button. If the first radio button  is clicked.  then value of gradeA should be true. If the second radio button is clicked, then value of gradeA should be false.  I tried the code you suggested, @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.StudentCourses[i].GradeA, true). But it results in error "Cannot convert lambda expression into string because it is not delegate type"

Comment: The code I gave you does not generate that error! (can only assume you use `RadioButton()` and not `RadioButtonFor()`)

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's working now, after changing to radioButtonFor